# does a 4U case need rails?

Tags: rack, rackmount

I just bought 3x cheap 4U cases for fitting microatx hardware. But rails are not included.

Are slider rails mandatory or only for convenience?

Servers are quite light. It's compute nodes. Only psu + Motherboard + CPU. No hardrives.

Comment: How do you plan to mount?  In a rack?  Rack with shelves?

Comment: I plan to mount it in a rack. Maybe I can alternate cheap server on top of good server with rails ?

Comment: @user1219721: Don't do this. The rails are designed to carry the load of *one* server, not many.

Comment: This is a useless question unless we know how the specific case is engineered to work. Please provide the make/model or even a product photo.

Comment: @ewwhite : I don't agree. The question is "Are slider rails mandatory or only for convenience?". This is a general scale question. It have been anwsered "most cases are not designed for use without rails, you should check about yours"

Comment: @user1219721 You didn't show us the enclosure you purchased. Without that information, we were all guessing.

Answer (score 3):

If it's acceptable for you to put them on 1U shelf plates in the rack, you don't *need* rails. However, you will loose 3U for 3 of these (I absolutely don't recommend stacking them on top of each on one shelf unit).

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on how deep the cases are. If they're particularly-shallow, you may be able to mount using the front rack-ears only.

Can you link to the product you purchased?

Comment: it's 500mm deep

Comment: At that depth, you can probably front-mount *if* the case appears to be engineered for it. (e.g. reinforced rack ears)

Comment: I'd call the manufacturer to verify that the ears can support the weight. 500mm is pretty shallow, and if the machines are light that might be the intended mounting technique.

Answer (score 1):

I've had cheap whitebox servers without rails in a 2-post rack... It's not ideal, but it works.